# tensor identity for cross product

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, tensor-products

I've read somewhere the following identity for a tensor rank 2

$ \nabla \times \nabla v =0 $

where $v$ is a vector of "j" components and $\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, such that $ \nabla v $ forms a tensor rank 2.

First off, is this true? Second, what if $v$ was replaced with a tensor of rank n? (I'm assuming you can take the gradient of any tensor rank, true?)

Comment: What do you mean by $\nabla \times {\bf A}$ for a $2$-tensor $\bf A$?

Comment: @Travis gradient cross 2-tensor. I guess I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: see page 20, A.147 on this link http://my.ece.ucsb.edu/York/Bobsclass/201B/W01/vectors.pdf